# How to pass a variable between pages WinJS?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, winjs

I'm trying to pass two variables from one page to the next. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you really mean variables or parameters?

Comment: Well, values in variables. I need to pass a string and an integer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Put this code in first page:

```
WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/pages/secondpage.html", yourvalue);
```

Then in second page to retrive the data use:

```
ready: function (element, options) {
    //your data yourvalue is inside options parametr 
}
```

[Very good example about navigation](http://windows8center.sourceforge.net/31-days-of-windows-8-day-13-navigation/)

[WinJS navigation example](http://www.codefoster.com/post/2012/06/21/Page-Navigation-in-Windows-8-JavaScript-Apps.aspx)

[WinJS navigation example 2](http://www.progware.org/Blog/post/%28Windows8%29-WinJS-single-page-navigation-and-ViewModels.aspx)

Comment: Can I only pass one value?

Comment: By navigation function only one value. But you can pass a object or array. Se the firs link for more information.

Comment: Thank you so much! I finally get it! lol...I was able to pass the variables successfully!

Answer (score 6):

Just wanted to include an example of passing multiple values as Norbert answered in his comment.

```
WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/pages/page2/page2.html", {value1:"hello",value2:"world"}
```